# Laravel Job Queue Dispatch Now not failing like normal

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have a job that I've made to test how failures work:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\ApiUser;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class FakeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $apiUser;

    public function __construct(ApiUser $apiUser) {
        $this->apiUser = $apiUser;
    }

    public function handle() {
        throw new Exception('time is even');
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception) {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
        $path = storage_path('logs/s3_logs/FakeJob_failed_' . Helper::generateRandomString(5) . '.txt');
        file_put_contents($path, $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I dispatch normally, it goes to the `failed` function and writes to file exactly as expected.

However when I do it like `FakeJob::dispatchNow($apiUser);`, it doesn't do that at all...

Is there a way to do `dispatchNow` that runs on the same process as the request, but fails as if it were queued normally?

Because at the moment, it looks like my only way is to do something like:

```
    $fakeJob = new FakeJob($apiUser);
    try {
        $fakeJob->handle();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $fakeJob->failed($e);
    }
```

Which is... fine I guess, but not ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am not wrong **dispatchNow()** is used to run the job synchronously but unfortunately, it does not call the failed method.

If you want your failed method to be called on job failed then you can use the below code.

```
FakeJob::dispatch($apiUser)->onConnection('sync');
```

It will run the job synchronously and also execute the failed method.

Comment: I'd not thought of trying that!

Comment: I'll try this now and report back

Comment: Ah, this does work! For the record, if the task does error, it goes to the failed method, BUT the `->dispatch()` call errors too, it doesn't catch it, so you have to try-catch the code you posted if you don't want it to error out there.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the Laravel code base (and docs), the `dispatchNow()` method executes the job synconously without interacting with any queues.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#synchronous-dispatching

In essence it will simply call the `handle()` method on your job and nothing more.

What you have done with your try/catch block may be the best solution for now but it could be worth raising this as a feature request with the Laravel team.

Answer (score 4):

A new `dispatchSync()` method will be made available in Laravel 8.0 when it is released in the coming months.
It'll dispatch the job on the sync queue just like @Keshari's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59579673/1484135) suggests.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#synchronous-dispatching
Commit: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/0b3ed6859046258fba2e0ab3340bdab33e4c82bd